# Can "And so?" serve as a request for completion or continuation of the thought? 

Tags: conversation

Can "Yes. And so?" serve as a request for completion or continuation of the thought?

For example:

> Merry: Jack, you can speak Japanese, French, Korean and Arabic.
>
> Jack: Yes. And so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can, but it's rather brusque, as if the speaker is saying 'Yeh, and what if I do?'

Comment: Can you, please, come up with something similar, but less brusque?

Comment: @brilliant: It would depend on the circumstances and the relationship between the two speakers. A more polite response might be 'Well, yes, I do as a matter of fact. Why do you ask?'

Comment: "Brusqueness", like most attitudes, is not conveyed by the words but by the tone, body language, facial expression etc. It's brief, but I don't believe it's necessarily brusque. Am I smiling, with raised eyebrows and an amused glint in my eye, or glaring, with a scowl?

Comment: @mickeyf: Probably easier with *"And so?"* than with *"What's it to you?"*, for example. But really, these are hostile/aggressive turns of phrase that no-one in their right mind should think can be "sanitised" by additional non-verbal communication.